# How to see list of purchased apps on the Apple Mac App Store in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mac, applications, mojave, install, mac-appstore

I have seen postings talk about a "Purchased" tab in the Mac App Store to see a list of apps you own. Then you can hit a button to install that app on a new Mac you own.

I do not see any "Purchased" tab on my Mac in the App Store when running macOS Mojave.

[image]

➥ How can I get a list of owned apps so that I might install them on a new Mac?

Comment: Click on your user name. You get the list of purchased items

Comment: @Mark Thanks, that worked. I made an Answer of that, with a screenshot.

Comment: Dear down-voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. Educate me as to how this Question fails to  guidelines of this site.

Answer (score 1):

## Click your username in corner

Notice your user account name in the lower left corner. Click that to change the listing to your purchased items.

From there, click the cloud-with-down-arrow icon to install an owned app to your Mac.

[image: screenshot of the Mac App Store app after having clicked the user account name in lower left corner.]